# Apollo Client refetch after mutation when paginating

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using  `"@apollo/client": "3.2.9"`. I have a page 1 with the first 10 items and I am calling the server to fetch first 10 items, works ok. I call the next page, this time with an extra variable (something like `skip`) and the next 10 items get fetch ok.

Next I do a mutation to add a new item (this would be added as a first item on the page 1). I am doing a mutation and I am refetching using

```
refetchQueries: ({ data }) => [
  {
    query: GET_MY_ITEMS,
    variables: {
      where: { type: { eq: data.updateMyItem.myType } },
    },
  },
],
awaitRefetchQueries: true,
```

and also I redirect to the first page. This works ok and the items on the first page get populated as expected with the new item on the top of the page.

The issue is happens when going back to second page, as that is still present in the cache. Because of that, item 1 on the second page is still the same as before when in fact item 1 on second page should now be item 10 from first page before mutation.

I am hoping I can clear all query results for a specific query from cache after mutation without variables (assume I can't know what the value of `skip` is). I would still prefer not completely disable cache for this query if possible.

Comment: When you go to the second page you may need to the fresh call and change the `fetch-policy` to `network-only`. It is possible that you're using any `cache` or `cache-and-network` policy and you have configured `InMemoryCache`. Can you add the full code or a working example in codesandbox? That will help me to understand better.

Comment: You are right, I am caching. I would like to continue to do so as the items don't change often. But after a mutation, I would like to clear all query results from the cache, regardless of what parameters they were queried with.

Comment: Then do one thing, Apollo does provide refetch functionality. You can use that in success of mutations.

Comment: That is what I am using and it works but only for the first page that has no variables. Problem is I cannot just refetch 20 pages when mutation completes. Might not even need them. That is why I am checking if there is a way to remove them from cache so they are refetched when needed (as they would no longer be in the cache)

Answer (score 1):

Rather reluctantly I have ended up using a different fetch policy to ensure that the data is up to date.

```
useLazyQuery(GET_MY_ITEMS, { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' });
```

This means I don't necessarily need to update the list after mutation but this feels suboptimal as every pagination results in the call to the server, I would much rather use cache most of the time and only call server when required.